# polygon of greatest area having vertices on parabola

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, maxima-minima

**question:**

[image]

**my attempt:**

any $t - $ point on parabola $y^2=2ax$ is given by $\left(\dfrac{at^2}{2}, at\right)$

area of polygon $\  = S=\left|\dfrac{(x_{1}y_{2}-y_{1}x_{2})+(x_{2}y_{3}-y_{2}x_{3})+.................+(x_{n}y_{1}-y_{n}x_{1})}{2}\right|$

where $(x_{i},y_{i})$ are cordinates of $ith$ vertex of polygon

$\implies \ S= \dfrac{a^2}{4}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} t_{1}t
_{2}(t_{1}-t_{2})\right) $

i don't know how to proceed further in order to find cordinates of $(n-1)th$ point on parabola  i.e, $A_{n-1} $ ,which isn't vertex of $(n-1)-gon$,  such that it's area is maximum

Comment: *"Out of these, except $A_{n-1}$, all are points."* What does this mean? Should it be that "all are **fixed** points" (since only $A_{n-1}$ moves)? Also, maybe I'm missing something, but ... If the vertices are connected in order, then the polygon is convex, so the area of the sub-polygon $A_1A_2\cdots A_{n-2} A_n$ (that is, skipping $A_{n-1}$) is fixed; we need only maximize the area of $\triangle A_{n-2}A_{n-1}A_n$. If that's so, then why not just say "Given two fixed points on a parabola, find the point on the arc between them that maximizes the area of the triangle"?

Comment: Okay, so suppose $P$ and $Q$ are on the parabola, and $R$ is a point on the arc between them. To maximize area of $\triangle PQR$, we need $R$ to be as far away as possible from $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$ (to maximize "height" relative to the fixed base); thus, the line through $R$ parallel to that line is as far away as possible: it must be *tangent* to the parabola. The location of the tangent line parallel to a given chord of a parabola is fairly well known, but also relatively easy to find.

Comment: amazing observation ............. your both comments can make solution just two  liner

Comment: How are the functions $t\mapsto A_i(t)$ defined, and how are the $t_i$ chosen? You are talking about "the" points. Which points?

Comment: i thought $t$ is just parameter of parabola $y^2=2ax$ which is used here to parameterize it's co-ordinates $\left(\dfrac{at^2}{2},at \right)$  and thus make it only  function of single variable i.e, $t$

Comment: @veereshpandey: Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $A_{n-1}= \left(\dfrac{at^2}{2}, at\right)$;

$A_{n-2}=\left(\dfrac{at_{n-2}^2}{2}, at_{n-2}\right)$

$A_{n}=\left(\dfrac{at_{n}^2}{2}, at_{n}\right)$

**by using blue's comment i proceeded as follows:**

**method 1 :** for maximum triangle area tangent at $A_{n-1}$ must be parllel to chord joining $A_{n}A_{n-2}$

slope of tangent at $A_{n}$ = slope of chord $A_{n}A_{n-2}$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{t}=2\left(\dfrac{at_{n-2}-at_{n}}{at_{n-2}^2-at_{n}^2}\right) \implies t= \dfrac{t_{n}+t_{n-2}}{2}$

**method 2 :**

area of triangle $\Delta= \dfrac{a^2}{4}\left[ t_{n}t_{n-2}(t_{n}-t_{n-2})+t_{n-2}\ t(t_{n-2}-t)+t\ t_{n}(t-t_{n})\right]=f(t)$

for maximising this area

$f'(t)=0\implies t= \dfrac{t_{n}^2-t_{n-2}^2}{2(t_{n}-t_{n-2)}}=\dfrac{t_{n}+t_{n-2}}{2}$

so, cordinates of $A_{n-1}$ will be

$A_{n-1}:\left[\dfrac{a}{2}\left(\dfrac{t_{n}+t_{n-2}}{2}\right)^2,a \left(\dfrac{t_{n}+t_{n-2}}{2}\right)\right]$