# Finding the ratio of areas between a polygon and the area of parabolas inscribed it

Tags: integration, geometry

This problem is taken from Facebook:

[image]

I want to know how to solve it. I've also found a discussion that might be related to this here: [polygon-of-greatest-area-having-vertices-on-parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976430/polygon-of-greatest-area-having-vertices-on-parabola). However, I'm not sure if that's gonna help. I also provide the area of a parobola from this [site](http://www.pde.za.net/content/formulas/properties_of_plane_areas/parabola.html), although, I don't know if it's reliable or not, hope you'll check that out and clarify.

And here's my attempt (I use the formula from the site I gave above):

We know for a regular polygon, the [area](https://mathmonks.com/polygon/area-of-polygon) is:

$$A_{\text{Polygon}} = \frac12 pa$$

Where: $p$ is the perimeter and $a$ is the apothem. **Note:** *the formula above will be written with different letters later*. And the area of $n$ parabolas inside a polygon with $n$ side is:

$$A_{\text{parabolas}} = \frac{2shn}{3}$$

Where $n$ is the number of the side, $h$ is the height of the parabola and $s$ is the length of the side of the polygon, i.e. $s=2a$, as $a$ is the half of the length of the minor diameter of parabola. The area in blue should be:

$$A_{\text{blue}} = sn\left(\frac12 \alpha - \frac23 h\right)$$

Where $\alpha$ is the apothem. That means the ratio is just

$$\text{Ratio} = \frac{A_{\text{blue}} }{A_{\text{Polygon}}}$$

However, back to my problem earlier, does the formula of the area of the parabola already satisfy the variation like the yellow parabolas drawn in this picture?:

[image]

**Edit:**

The poster says that each parabola is tangent to the adjacent parabola at each vertex of the polygon where they meet. It's mean that the parabola is unique right? So, how's it gonna be?

Comment: Can you give a link to the facebook problem?

Comment: @coffeemath it's in a group. The group itself is set to be private. So there's no way the link can be shared unless one joins the group.

Comment: Can you then give the name of the group so those who want to could try to join the group?

Comment: @coffeemath the name is MATH LOVERS with capital letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio of area of a parabola to the surrounding yellow rectangle is known  two-thirds,established by elementary integration.  The symmetry line cuts  the tangent at half height of the center line. ( Can be given here once again if required ).

In the following the ratio of white spiky parabola area to full right triangle ratio is computed as $\dfrac13$ fraction that way.

[image]

It holds for any d depth of parabola *due to symmetry for any integral $n$* or for a regular polygon, independent of $n$.

Comment: I'm perplexed, sorry. I've tried the integration for $n=4$ (rectangle) and the ratio of area of the complement of parabolas to the area of the rectangle is $\frac13$ not $\frac23$. Did you mistype?

Comment: Yes,correted that typo.

Comment: Btw thank you for your comments. It really helps me to understand. I didn't think of integration. It's really brilliant!